# ListView cannot be updated (or accessed) from a module in visual basic 2015

Tags: vb.net, listview

I try to use a listview on a GUI for providing feedback to the user about what is going on behind during a long procedure. In the module, there are four sub procedures in the main procedure and the last column in the list view shows status of them such as pending, running, or completed. Thus, when a sub procedure is completed, the subitem on the corresponding line should be updated as "Completed".

By the way, I can add items (4 rows x 3 columns) to the listview without having any problem when the GUI which is a form basically, is shown (form load).

In the script below, when I call that function by a button click event everything works well. However, in the module, the result of message box is zero while there are four items already added in the listview. The line after the message box gives the following error:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

What is the problem with it? Thanks in advance!

```
Module Module1
 Sub CreateReport()
  Call SubProcedure1()
  'Update listview
  MessageBox.Show("There is/are: " & form6_ins.ListView1.Items.Count & " item(s)!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
  Call ListView_ScheduleUpdate1(0, 2, "Completed", 1, 2, "Running", ListView1)    'Throws Error
  Call SubProcedure2()
  'Update listview as well
  Call SubProcedure3()
  'Update listview as well
  Call SubProcedure4()
  'Update listview as well
 End Sub

'Function to update the listview items
 Public Function ListView_ScheduleUpdate1(ByVal itemNumX As Integer, ByVal subItemNumX As Integer, ByVal givenFeedbackX As String,
                                ByVal itemNumY As Integer, ByVal subItemNumY As Integer, ByVal givenFeedbackY As String, ByRef LV As ListView)

    LV.Items(itemNumX).SubItems(subItemNumX).Text = givenFeedbackX
    LV.Items(itemNumY).SubItems(subItemNumY).Text = givenFeedbackY
    LV.Refresh()
 End Function
End Module 


'Form
Public Class Form1

 Private Sub But_Report_DSchedule_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles But_Report_DSchedule.Click
    MessageBox.Show("There is/are: " & ListView1.Items.Count & " item(s)!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Call ListView_ScheduleUpdate1(0, 2, "Completed", 1, 2, "Running", ListView1)
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If Sub Main is called before the form is loaded then the ListView does not actually exist yet. You should not be trying to access properties of controls on the form until after it has loaded. From the book "Hardcore Visual Basic":

> When a form is loaded, the sequence of events is the following:
>
> A form is a class, and all classes have an Initialize event. Form_Initialize is called (or fired, as control developers describe calling events) as soon as you touch any variable or property of a form. Use this event to initialize variables private to the form. Normally, you should not touch any form or control properties here because doing so fires the next event.
>
> Form_Load fires after Form_Initialize as the visual elements of the form are being created and default values are being assigned to properties. Normally, you should avoid doing anything that will draw something on the form because that causes an automatic firing of the next event. It might be tempting to call Show in Form_Load and then do further processing with the visible form, but you’re usually better off doing this in the next event.
>
> Form_Activate fires after you have loaded and shown the form. It’s possible to load a form without showing it; in this case, Form_Activate isn’t fired until you call the Show method. Form_Activate is also called when you switch from one modeless form to another, or when you switch between MDI forms (but not when you return focus from 
>   another application). If your application has modeless or MDI forms, don’t do anything in Form_Activate that you want to happen only once. Or use a static variable (such as fNotFirst) to protect against multiple initializations in Form_Activate. 
>   The interactions between the three initialization events can be confusing. Sometimes trial and error is the only way to figure out the right initialization sequence for your application.

Comment: @CB_Ron- Thanks for your reply. Sub Main is called by clicking a button on the form. Actually, it is not the main sub, form is loaded in the main sub. I had labeled it mistakenly. The form is there before that sub.